# Generic protocols on Swift

Tags: swift, generics, kotlin

I want to translate some Kotlin code on Swift, and I have problems with it. What's the right way to write this code on Swift?

```
interface Foo<T>{
    fun <F>foo(action: (T) -> Foo<F>): Foo<F>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype T
    func foo<F>(action: (T) -> F) -> F where F: Foo
}
```

Comment: Yeah you're right, I jumped the gun on my response and didn't notice the unused generic; updating my response

Comment: why not simply `func foo<F: Foo>(action: (T) -> F) -> F ` ?

Comment: Its the same functionally speaking; I left it as is in case OP needs any additional constraints with the `associatedtype` for the function